# IdentityServer4 - A security error has occured

Tags: asp.net, ssl, asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with ASP .NET Core WebAPI and I'm having issues with accessing the discovery page programmatically

```
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://<api>:1337");
```

If I host the API's (IdentityServer and the protected API) on my localhost, everything works, I don't even need to use https.... probabily it doesn't throw the ..`HTTPS is required` if the host's name is localhost ?

So, I began creating a self-signed certificate on server's IIS, stored it in the Personal Certificate store.
But when I connect from the outside (browser) I get the error :

```
This site is not secure - Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID
```

After a bit of search and no luck finding anything, I've installed the same certificate on my laptop (so I can access the API without getting the warning).
Now I'm not getting any warning and the discovery JSON is available. to be seen (from the browser)

But programmatically I still get the same error.

**Error**

```
Error connecting to https://:1337/.well-known/openid-configuration: An error occurred while sending the request.
```

**Exception StackTrace**

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryClient.<GetAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
```

**InnerException Message:**

```
A security error occurred
```

**Inner Exception StackTrace**

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
```

**EDIT 01**
Adding the same self-signed certificate from the Server to my laptop onto the Trusted certify container works, partially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the self-signed certificate(for IIS) I've encountered another error, it was related to the self-signed certificate for the JWT signing, I had to assign rights to my domain user behind the application pool (not ApplicationPoolIdentity) for Read/Write on the certificate.
I've done this through MMC

Comment: I have the similar issue, but after done all the above changes i m still getting the error message("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297211/an-error-occurred-while-sending-the-request-to-identityserver4").